# trying to use value after slash as a php variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've seen other similar questions asked- but not covering the problem I am having with the `htaccess` file in my folder.

I have the domain www.example.com, which in my hosting account I specify the folder `my_website` and I put all my files in there.

But I am trying to allow the user to pass a value without having to remember to write `www.example.com/index.php?value=xyz`. I am able to use a re-write rule in the htaccess file that lets the person write: `www.example.com/xyz` and `xyz` will be converted to a `$_GET` variable. To do this I am using:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This works fine. The problem is that now when you type `www.example.com` *without* any slash and value, it doesn't send the user to `index.php` as intended, it tells them they don't have permission to access `/` on this server.

Can someone tell me how to write a rule that will send the user to index.php and convert a value after a slash as a variable to be used in the script - but doesn't mind if there's no slash either?

Comment: **example.com** has nothing to do with the rule you posted. Your rule is applied only when there is an uri after the domain name eg **example.com/uri** . Do you have any other rules?

Comment: I don't have any other rules.  So why is it that when you go to example.com without any slash and value, it doesn't just land on index.php?  How can I make it work in both cases (with slash and without?).  Thanks!

Comment: Where is your htaccess file located?

Comment: it is in the same folder as index.php and this is also the folder where my server would look for index.html, home.html, etc. when a browser is pointed at the domain in question.

Comment: Does it work if you put this line  above your existing RewriteRule **RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]**

Comment: That does the trick.  Thank you!

Comment: I actually spoke too soon.  It did what I wanted it too.. but now all of the links on the site have broken.

Comment: that's probably because of the change in base uri. You can fix it by adding a base tag in head section of your webpage **<base href="/">** or make your relative links absolute by spacifing a leading slash eg **/foo.png** **/style.css** instead of **foo.png , style.css**

Comment: The index page is working, but when I click on an link, the index page comes up again.  And the correct url shows up in the address bar (the one I'd expect to see based on the link.)  But the only page that will load is index.php..arg!